# Динамическое продление цикла for (По-другому не могу описать проблему). Python

Tags: python

Имеется следующее задание:

[image: Задание]

[image: Задание]

И следующий код:

```
programLines = str(input()).split('#')
answer = ''

for _ in range(int(programLines[-1])):

    codeLines = str(input())
    codeLinesList = codeLines.split('#')

    if codeLinesList[0] == '':
        pass
    else:
        answer += ' ' + codeLines

answer = answer.split(' ')
print(*answer, sep='\n')
```

Проблема заключается в том, что количество циклов зависит от количества кода, то есть от первой вводимой строки (12), но самих строк больше (16) и из-за этого скрипт срабатывает не до конца. Вряд ли есть способы динамически продлевать цикл, но какое количество повторений цикла нужно указать, чтобы при вводе каждой строки в переменную codeLines цикл останавливался не на 12 шаге, а на 16? Просто продлить цикл, очевидно, не подойдет, т.к. входные данные могут быть любыми.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще обращаете внимание на число 12? Считывайте программу, пока не закончится ввод, потом удаляйте лишнее, и уже потом сверяйте количество  получившихся строк с заданным числом.

Comment: Замените `for` на `while`.

Answer (score 0):

1. str(input()) не имеет смысла так как возвращается строка
2. исспользование _ нижнего подчёркивания дурной тон, ведущий к трудноуловимым ошибкам
3. split('#') не верен так как `yes=input('u is arrested #')` поломает код, можно испльзовать регулярное выражение
4. в вашем случае можно использовать модуль "black"
5. `programLines = str(input()).split('#')` не рационально так как нужно удалить первый символ, а не разбивать строку в список то есть `prgrmLines=prgrmLines[1:]`

вы имели ввиду рекурсию  или безконечный цикл. `while answer.find('\n')!=input('строк')[1:]: #' 'заменён на символ переноса строк тк тупо юзать пробел как разделитель результатов`

Comment: Использование нижнего подчеркивания в выражениях типа `for _ in ...` - прекрасный тон, поощрямый авторами языка.